# How to Create Custom, Instant, Arrow-Shaped ToolTip with unique shape?

Tags: c++, tooltip, qt5

On many web-pages nowadays, you'll frequently see instant tooltips with an arrow that points to their target, similar to:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_arrow_bottom

(More specifically, I'm looking for something like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Jedht9Arec)

How would you exactly replicate this in QT? I'm not necessarily looking for something super automated, just something that can be given a position to appear at, and a function call to remove it. Furthermore, if possible, it should have curved, anti-aliased corners.

I've tried using custom QToolTip, but it's behavior does not meet my standards. I've also tried a custom QDialog with a Popup flag, but it freezes the dialog it appears above.

Any recommendations on how to proceed?

---

As requested by two comments below, here is the code for the QDialog scenario previously referenced. Prepare yourself, it's a lot:

```
// Assuming "this" is the parent dialog
QDialog* popup = new QDialog(this, Qt::Popup);
popup->show();
```

This code blocks mouse hover events of the parent dialog (the "this" object), thus making it unsuitable as a tool-tip replacement.

Comment: Is there any code of what you've tried to accomplish? Perhaps it's freezing due to an error in your code you're missing. Please read over [how to make a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future reference, as we're not going to kick back and write this for you. You need to help us help you. :)

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JamesWhyte Updated, though didn't think it was necessary since it pretty much boils down to two lines of code as I described (create QDialog with popup flag; then show it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QWidget::setMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask) to specify custom shape of a widget. Additionally you'll have to set widget's window flags to include [`Qt::ToolTip`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum).